# How to merge two similar database tables into one SelectList

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, selectlist

I have two database tables that each have two columns that are the exact same -- Name and Designator. I want to create a SelectList combining the two tables using Designator as the value and Name as the text. This is what I've tried, but the options come out as "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.SelectListItem"

I've tried a few other variations with no luck.

Does anyone know how to do this properly?

Here's the code:

```cs
        public SelectList GetOrgsSelectList()
        {
            SelectList flts = new SelectList(_context.Flights, "Designator", "Name");
            SelectList elems = new SelectList(_context.Elements, "Designator", "Name");
            return new SelectList(flts.Concat(elems));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merged the data before put them into the selectlist.

```
    public SelectList GetOrgsSelectList()
    {
        var merged = _context.Flights.Select(x => new {
            x.Designator,
            x.Name
        }).Concat(_context.Elements.Select(x => new {
            x.Designator,
            x.Name
        }));
        return new SelectList(merged, "Designator", "Name");
    }
```